# How to Import or Query a Range from Google Sheets into Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets-named-ranges

I'm using Google Docs, the word processor, and am seeking to import a named range sourced in Google sheets into my Google Docs file.

Do the field code feature or any other feature in Google Docs support this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs hasn't  a built-in "field code feature" but you could  use Google Apps Script to insert a Google Sheets named or another programming platform together with some Google APIs.

Maybe there is a Google Docs extension that already does what you are looking for.

References

- https://developers.google.com/docs
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs

Comment: If a Google Apps script is used, would the script in a Google Docs file made accessible to "Anyone with the link" run whenever anyone opens the file or would users need to have access to Google Apps Script to run the script?  I'm looking to automate as much of this process as possible with minimum user input.

Comment: @Catalyx That is a too broad question as there are several ways that Google Apps Script could be used and you didn't described the expected user interactions with your document.

Comment: Pardon not specifying the intended user experience.  I was looking for a native Google Docs off-the-shelf solution and since, as you note, that is not available, the scope of the question has changed. As one more experienced with StackEchange WebApps, please advise whether to edit the question or start a fresh question. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. It looks that you want to make a follow-up question. The "correct way" to proceed is to post a new question into the proper site (web applications is for question about using web apps like Google Docs and including with some limitations extending them by using Google Apps Script or similar platforms). If the scope is beyond what a "poweruser" of a web application could do, please ask in [meta.se] if there is a site for that kind of questions as developing a web app is off-topic in this site and it's a very broad topic..

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)